# Add Subview To Custom UI Button Class

Tags: ios, swift

**Objective:**

> When the user clicks the custom button, a blank UIView should appear covering the button.

I've added my code to a new Swift project which looks like this

```
import UIKit

class DownloadUIButton: UIButton {
    var isDownloading: Bool? = false
    func addView() {
        let view = UIView(frame: self.frame)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.addSubview(view)
    }
}

class ViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    fileprivate let tableView: UITableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300), style: UITableViewStyle.plain)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.setupTableView()

    }

    fileprivate func setupTableView() {
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        tableView.isOpaque = true
        view.addSubview(self.tableView)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "CellIdentifier")

        let buttonSize = 30
        let btn = DownloadUIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize))
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        btn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleDownload(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.addSubview(btn)

        return cell
    }

    @objc func handleDownload(_ btn: DownloadUIButton) {
        btn.addView()
    }

}
```

However, the project gives this error:

2017-10-28 12:55:41.558522+0100 TestProject[21392:1779236] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalid', reason: 'layer  is a part of cycle in its layer tree'

Comment: If I'm understanding this right, and all you want to do is hide the button after it's been clicked, why not just set the `isHidden` property on the button?

Comment: You understand correctly. However, this problem is an abstraction of a more difficult problem in which I need to show a view on top of the UIButton.

Comment: Okay, wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a view appear in front of your button, I'd just make them sibling views with the same frame. Have the custom view's `isHidden` set to `true` at launch time, and when the button's clicked, set the button's `isHidden` to `true` and the custom view's `isHidden` to `false`. Alternately, if you actually want the button to be visible behind transparent parts of the custom view, you can use `sendSubview(toBack:)` to make the button appear behind the custom view.